# Convert all non-null to lower case

Tags: pandas

Apologies I am a Pandas novice. I am trying to convert all values in a dataframe to lower case except if they are null. I try the following:

```
Df = df.apply (lambda x: x if pd.isna (x) else x.astype (str).str.lower()
```

but get an error

```
\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
  .format (self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index oss')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `fillna` with some unique string then

```
df.fillna('thisnanwillreplaceback').apply(lambda x :x.str.lower()).replace('thisnanwillreplaceback',np.nan)
Out[275]: 
     A    C
0  aad  aad
1  aac  aac
2  NaN  aad
```

Simple data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['AAD','AAC',np.nan],'C':['AAD','AAC','AAD']})
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. For my own knowledge, I would still like to understand what I was doing wrong there

Comment: @Ursula you are looking for `df.applymap (lambda x: x if pd.isna (x) else x.lower())`